# Game over when both players die

Tags: unity, c#

I watched the Unity Space Shooter video [tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/introduction) and then I have added a second player. I can not seem to get the 'Game Over' when they both die. It will happen when one player dies but not both. Below is my code.

```
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public GameObject explosion;
  public GameObject playerExplosion;
  public GameObject player2Explosion;
  public int scoreValue;

  private bool P1Dead;
  private bool P2Dead;
  private GameController gameController;

  void Start ()
  {
    P1Dead = false;
    P2Dead = false;
    GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag ("GameController");

    if (gameControllerObject != null)
      gameController = gameControllerObject.GetComponent < GameController> ();

    if (gameController == null)
      Debug.Log ("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
    if (other.CompareTag ("Boundary") || other.CompareTag ("Enemy"))
      return;

    if (explosion != null)
      Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    if (other.CompareTag ("Player"))
    {
      Instantiate (playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
      P1Dead = true;
    }

    if (other.CompareTag ("Player2")) 
    {
      P2Dead = true;
      Instantiate (player2Explosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
    }

    if (P1Dead == true & P2Dead == true)
      gameController.GameOver ();

    gameController.AddScore (scoreValue);
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: Style point: generally it's considered poor style to compare Booleans to a constant (`if(P1Dead == true)`), in preference to using the value directly (`if(P1Dead)`).

Answer (score 4):

`if (P1Dead == true & P2Dead == true)`

That looks like a typo. Performing bitwise "and" instead of logic &.

Try this:

`if (P1Dead == true && P2Dead == true)`

Comment: Lynx eyes, that you have :P

Comment: It doesn't make any difference though, since bitwise and has the same effect as logical and for booleans.